# angular templating: ng-repeat comma-separated links

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I got really disappointed with angular... I'm trying to do a quite simple presentation-layer stuff and I can see no good solution while browsing the web (and stack overflow as well).

The case is: **I've got a list of elements that I will generate links to, all of them will be comma-separated in HTML**. Let's say it's:

```
var list = [{id: 1, name: "ab"},{id:2, name: "cd"}, ...];
```

My link should look something like:

```
<a href="#/someLink/{{ el.id }}">{{ el.name }}</a>
```

Easy, isn't it? So, basing on other SO questions, I tried this:

```
<a ng-repeat="el in list" href="#/someLink/{{ el.id }}">{{ el.name }}</a>{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
```

which doesn't work, because this `ng-repeat` is already inside another ng-repeat and `$index`, `$last`, `$first` is probably caught by the outer `ng-repeat` values instead of the inner one, as I want.

Moreover, I don't like making a HTML one-liner that will do 5 things at a time, because [1] it costs to read it and [2] it's easier to mess something, while changing, because of the complexity. So I would definitely prefer to split this into more lines. *But* at the same time, I don't want a space before the comma, i.e. `el1 , el2`. It should be `el1, el2`. And the last thing - the comma shall *not* be in the link, because only the element name should be linked; comma is justa separator, right?

It seems a really trivial case todo in js-templating engines (mustache, hbs, etc.), python, php, ruby, everything - and I can't find a clean solution in angular. Not to mention that builtin `ng-repeat` doesn't support such fundamental feature.

Comment: your $last is outside inner ng-repeat, you need to wrap with span tag for both including tag, and use ng-repeat on that span.

Comment: @YOU Yes, and this makes the template even less readable... Anyway, this is still not the answer, since I **don't** want the comma to become a part of the link. I wrote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
<span ng-repeat="el in list">
    <a href="#/someLink/{{ el.id }}">{{ el.name }}</a>{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
</span>
```

It is just a slight modification form your code, just added an outer span for the repeat

Comment: I don't like it that much, since my code is more complex in fact. And this becomes hardly readable. But it's angular issue, not a problem with your solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want inner ng-repeat to catch $last, put $last inside inner ng-repeat.

```
<span ng-repeat="el in list">
    <a href="#/someLink/{{ el.id }}">{{ el.name }}</a><span ng-if="!$last">, </span>
</span>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't satisfy `el1, el2`. It produces `el1 , el2`. Please read the question.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz, put it in the same line then. that's about html, not related to angular.